# Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3101 - Rails / Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, microservices, net-http

I'm trying to ping one of our Rails Microservices (handles emails) from our app, and I'm getting the title error.

Our microservice is running in docker on `localhost:3101`, whilst our app is on localhost:3000 on docker also - I've pinged it with postman requests and it's working fine.

I've set our auth token and email service API in our ENV variables like so:-

```
EMAIL_SERVICE=http://localhost:3101
EMAIL_SERVICE_TOKEN=1234
```

Here's my `EmailService`:-

```
class EmailService
  require 'net/http'

  HEADER = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }.freeze
  ENDPOINTS = {
    root: ENV['EMAIL_SERVICE'],
    test_email: {
      post: {
        url: '/api/test_email'
      }
    }
  }

  def initialize
    @token = ENV['EMAIL_SERVICE_TOKEN']
  end

  def call_api(section, action, data, method='POST')
    address_url = ENDPOINTS[section][action][:url]
    uri = URI.parse("#{ENDPOINTS[:root]}#{address_url}")

    # Create the HTTP objects
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    if method == 'POST'
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(
        uri.request_uri,
        HEADER
      )
      request.body = data.merge({ auth_token: @token }).to_json

    else
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(
        uri.request_uri,
        HEADER
      )
    end

    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.request(request)
  end
end
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that both of those microservices run on separate docker containers.

I think the problem is that when docker receives your request from outside of the container and then tries to make an HTTP request to `localhost` it actually is making request to its OWN `localhost` (so inside the container) and not the `localhost` of your machine. To fix this, instead of trying to send request to `localhost` make the app inside the docker send the request to `host.docker.internal:DESIRED_PORT` this tells docker to use `localhost` of it's host machine.

You can read more about that here:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: Thanks for your reply - this was correct.  I had to add it to the network in my services docker-compose file, and also change the port (since I was using the external port rather than the internal one).